# Assigning null to a foreign key in EntityFramework Code first approach

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I want to make a virtual object (Details) to null, my sample Class details below:

```
public class test
{
public List<stud> students{get;set;}
}

public class stud
{
public int id{get;set;}
public string name{get;set;}
[ForeignKey("Details")]
public int DetailId { get; set; }
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Details Details{ get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
public string a {get;set;}
public string b{get;set;}
}

test.students= await db.students.where(x=>x.id==12).ToListAsync();
foreach(var a in test.students)
{
a.Details=null;
db.savechanges();//but the Details obj is not being set to null.
}
```

Can someone please help me to set Details obj as null?

Comment: Have you tried to set Details as nullable: `public virtual Details? Details { get; set; }` ?

Comment: I don't want to set Details as nullable as always Details is going to have value except the scenario/functionality I mentioned above. For this scenario only I want to make it as null.

Comment: @VagnerLucas `Details` is a class, so it is already nullable.  `Details?` has no meaning and will not compile.